Shortcuts for view split on left and right disappear
I use Ubuntu 23.10.1, and set shortcuts for "View split on left" and "View split on right" as Alt + Left and Alt + Right respectively. For some reason once in a while the setting resets to "Disabled" spontaneously. Other custom shortcuts work fine. What could be the problem?

Difficult to guess. "Resetting" would mean these keyboard shortcuts are actually being set, because they are the default in Ubuntu. When you cannot use these keys, what is the output of gsettings get org.gnome.mutter.keybindings toggle-tiled-left and …right? It is advised to provide information on your hardware. Also check whether the issue reproduces without Gnome Shell extensions enabled. If not, then enable them one by one until the issue reappears.

I have the same issue.
